# Collapsing divs to 100% of iphone layout

Tags: css, html

I truly wouldn't be posting a question if I hadn't already spent hours digging through files and researching. I must really not know what I'm looking for :-|

I want to know how and why divs in a container (or the container itself) can change to 100% width when a responsive design is scaled to iphone dimensions - like the below:

http://demo2.woothemes.com/whitelight/about/

the sidebar sits underneath the main content, then the divs inside stretch to 100%

It's driving me absolutely mad! Any help / direction must appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Media query responsive layout example:

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ayojan/1/edit

Resize browser to see effect.

```
div {
  outline:solid black;
}
.content {
  width:80%;
  float:left;
}
.sidebar {
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
}
  .content {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }

}
```

Key points: inside the media query you unfloat the elements (float:none) and set them to width: 100%;

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should have been clearer. I want to know how to force the sidebar to drop down a level and for the adjacent content to take up 100% — i'm guessing this is in the @media code you mentioned.

I should say I'm interested in generally forcing divs to drop down when the width goes below a certain threshold. In the example I posted above you can see that all the footer widget areas do exactly this.

Comment: If you want something dropped, you just need to remove float property or set it to none. (or remove float propperty on the content so the sidebar doesnt float)

Comment: This is the confusing part for me...

See: http://demo2.woothemes.com/whitelight/shop/baseball-t/ 

the image gallery and summary are also dropping down at iphone width. I don't understand how they can be set as roughly 30% of the page, then suddenly change to 100% -- after all 30% remains 30% however you scale

they don't seem to be set anywhere in @media

Comment: media query means it applies only to that browser width. So if its just for iphone yes, set it there.

Comment: the point of this is to modify a normal website for iphone use

Comment: yes, so you put your iphone specific css in the appropraite media queries. At this point im not sure what are you asking specifically?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to make divs of misc width wrap to the next line, at 100% full width, when media was below a certain point.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: see my updated anwser, i hope this makes it clear how this whole media query thing works.

Comment: Woop! Many thanks. Suddenly it all becomes clear and I feel an airhead :o)